# JSON Parsing using minimal-json and Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a java program which retrieves data for a particular TV show and returns a JSON response with the details.
My problem is with parsing the JSON response to get one particular key-value pair, namely the "first_aired_iso" string, which gives the air date for that episode.

Here is the URL which calls the API

`String api_url = "http://api.trakt.tv/show/season.json/<api-key>/the-walking-dead/1";`

And here is the corresponding JSON response

---

> ! `[
>      {
>         "season":1,
>         "episode":1,
>         "number":1,
>         "tvdb_id":2493011,
>         "title":"Days Gone Bye",
>         "overview":"Rick searches for his family after emerging from a coma into a world terrorized by the walking dead. Morgan and Duane, whom he meets along the way, help teach Rick the new rules for survival.",
>         "first_aired":1288584000,
>         "first_aired_iso":"2010-10-31T21:00:00-05:00",
>         "first_aired_utc":1288598400,
>         "url":"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/1",
>         "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-1.22.jpg",
>         "images":{
>            "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-1.22.jpg"
>         },
>         "ratings":{
>            "percentage":89,
>            "votes":763,
>            "loved":733,
>            "hated":30
>         },
>         "watched":true,
>         "in_collection":true,
>         "in_watchlist":false,
>         "rating":false,
>         "rating_advanced":0
>      },
>      {
>         "season":1,
>         "episode":2,
>         "number":2,
>         "tvdb_id":2493181,
>         "title":"Guts",
>         "overview":"Rick unknowingly causes a group of survivors to be trapped by walkers. The group dynamic devolves from accusations to violence, as Rick must confront an enemy far more dangerous than the undead.",
>         "first_aired":1289192400,
>         "first_aired_iso":"2010-11-07T21:00:00-06:00",
>         "first_aired_utc":1289210400,
>         "url":"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/2",
>         "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-2.22.jpg",
>         "images":{
>            "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-2.22.jpg"
>         },
>         "ratings":{
>            "percentage":87,
>            "votes":533,
>            "loved":507,
>            "hated":26
>         },
>         "watched":true,
>         "in_collection":true,
>         "in_watchlist":false,
>         "rating":false,
>         "rating_advanced":0
>      },
>      {
>         "season":1,
>         "episode":3,
>         "number":3,
>         "tvdb_id":2656081,
>         "title":"Tell It to the Frogs",
>         "overview":"After returning to the camp with the department store survivors and an emotional reunion with his wife and son, Rick decides to go against Shane's advice and go back to Atlanta for Merle Dixon and his dropped bag of guns accompanied by Merle's younger brother, Darryl Dixon, as well as Glenn and T-Dog.",
>         "first_aired":1289797200,
>         "first_aired_iso":"2010-11-14T21:00:00-06:00",
>         "first_aired_utc":1289815200,
>         "url":"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/3",
>         "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-3.22.jpg",
>         "images":{
>            "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-3.22.jpg"
>         },
>         "ratings":{
>            "percentage":85,
>            "votes":484,
>            "loved":458,
>            "hated":26
>         },
>         "watched":true,
>         "in_collection":true,
>         "in_watchlist":false,
>         "rating":false,
>         "rating_advanced":0
>      },
>      {
>         "season":1,
>         "episode":4,
>         "number":4,
>         "tvdb_id":2656091,
>         "title":"Vatos",
>         "overview":"While still in search of Merle, the group tries to retrieve the bag of guns but are attacked by several living men who are also after the weapons. The group manages to grab the injured attacker; however, several of the attackers escape and take Glenn hostage. Back at camp a large group of walkers venture up the hill and take the survivors by surprise.",
>         "first_aired":1290402000,
>         "first_aired_iso":"2010-11-21T21:00:00-06:00",
>         "first_aired_utc":1290420000,
>         "url":"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/4",
>         "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-4.22.jpg",
>         "images":{
>            "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-4.22.jpg"
>         },
>         "ratings":{
>            "percentage":88,
>            "votes":490,
>            "loved":467,
>            "hated":23
>         },
>         "watched":true,
>         "in_collection":true,
>         "in_watchlist":false,
>         "rating":false,
>         "rating_advanced":0
>      },
>      {
>         "season":1,
>         "episode":5,
>         "number":5,
>         "tvdb_id":2656101,
>         "title":"Wildfire",
>         "overview":"Rick leads the group to the CDC after the attack on the camp. Jim must make a terrible life and death decision.",
>         "first_aired":1291006800,
>         "first_aired_iso":"2010-11-28T21:00:00-06:00",
>         "first_aired_utc":1291024800,
>         "url":"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/5",
>         "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-5.22.jpg",
>         "images":{
>            "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-5.22.jpg"
>         },
>         "ratings":{
>            "percentage":87,
>            "votes":460,
>            "loved":443,
>            "hated":17
>         },
>         "watched":true,
>         "in_collection":true,
>         "in_watchlist":false,
>         "rating":"love",
>         "rating_advanced":10
>      },
>      {
>         "season":1,
>         "episode":6,
>         "number":6,
>         "tvdb_id":2656111,
>         "title":"TS-19",
>         "overview":"Rick and the group are allowed into the CDC by a strange doctor, but all is not what it seems in their newfound haven. ",
>         "first_aired":1291611600,
>         "first_aired_iso":"2010-12-05T21:00:00-06:00",
>         "first_aired_utc":1291629600,
>         "url":"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/6",
>         "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-6.22.jpg",
>         "images":{
>            "screen":"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-6.22.jpg"
>         },
>         "ratings":{
>            "percentage":87,
>            "votes":465,
>            "loved":440,
>            "hated":25
>         },
>         "watched":true,
>         "in_collection":true,
>         "in_watchlist":false,
>         "rating":"love",
>         "rating_advanced":10
>      }
>   ]`

---

Well, you get the idea...
I just need to extract the key value for "first_aired_iso" for each episode.

Here is my code to do that

```
        String s = response.toString();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonstr = gson.toJson(s);
        System.out.println(jsonstr);
        JsonArray json = JsonArray.readFrom(jsonstr);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            System.out.println(json.get(i).asString());
        }
```

Problem is, there is absolutely no response after printing the raw JSON output. 
I can't get it to enter the loop at all.

For reference, please check http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/

Comment: Basically, you've got an array of "objects" (maps/dictionaries), though some details (such as ratings) are maps within the individual program maps.  "first_aired_iso" would be an entry in each map of the array, with a String for a value.  Iterate through each JSON array element, cast the element to a JsonObject (??), then use, probably, `get("first_aired_iso")` to extract the String result.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't return anything.
Used every possible JSON parser out there.
Gson, org.JSON, simple-json, Jackson, minimal-json, everything.

Comment: I doubt it.  To extract the individual element use `JsonObject show = (JsonObject)(json.get(i));`.  (Or perhaps `JsonObject show = json.get(i).asObject();`.)  Then `String time = show.get("first_aired_iso").asString();`.

Comment: Study json.org to learn the JSON syntax, and use an online parser such as http://json.parser.online.fr/ to see the structure of your JSON string.

Comment: That is precisely what I did. I even tried a custom method, but that only extracted only the first episode's first_aired_iso.

            `Gson gson = new Gson();

            String jsonstr = gson.toJson(s);

            JsonArray json = JsonArray.readFrom(jsonstr);

            JsonObject show = json.get(0).asObject();

            String time = show.get("first_aired_iso").asString();

            System.out.println(time);`

Comment: If you want to get them all you have to loop on the array (`json.get(i)`) and collect each one as a separate operation.  Unless your objects support a "get all elements of this type" operation, and I don't think that would be a "minimal" implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = response.toString();
JsonArray json = JsonArray.readFrom(s);
for (int i = 0; i < json.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject show = json.get(i).asObject();
    int episode = show.get("episode").asInt();
    String time = show.get("first_aired_iso").asString();
    System.out.println("Episode " + episode + " - " + time);
}
```

Thanks a lot HotLicks! :)

Comment: Close.  Change `get(0)` to `get(i)`.  And make your loop be `int i = 0; i < json.count(); i++`.  (Though "count" may be "size" or some other name -- I don't know your toolset.)

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but forgot to mention it in the comment.
Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "[ { \"season\":1, \"episode\":1, \"number\":1, \"tvdb_id\":2493011, \"title\":\"Days Gone Bye\", \"overview\":\"Rick searches for his family after emerging from a coma into a world terrorized by the walking dead. Morgan and Duane, whom he meets along the way, help teach Rick the new rules for survival.\", \"first_aired\":1288584000, \"first_aired_iso\":\"2010-10-31T21:00:00-05:00\", \"first_aired_utc\":1288598400, \"url\":\"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/1\", \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-1.22.jpg\", \"images\":{ \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-1.22.jpg\" }, \"ratings\":{ \"percentage\":89, \"votes\":763, \"loved\":733, \"hated\":30 }, \"watched\":true, \"in_collection\":true, \"in_watchlist\":false, \"rating\":false, \"rating_advanced\":0 }, { \"season\":1, \"episode\":2, \"number\":2, \"tvdb_id\":2493181, \"title\":\"Guts\", \"overview\":\"Rick unknowingly causes a group of survivors to be trapped by walkers. The group dynamic devolves from accusations to violence, as Rick must confront an enemy far more dangerous than the undead.\", \"first_aired\":1289192400, \"first_aired_iso\":\"2010-11-07T21:00:00-06:00\", \"first_aired_utc\":1289210400, \"url\":\"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/2\", \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-2.22.jpg\", \"images\":{ \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-2.22.jpg\" }, \"ratings\":{ \"percentage\":87, \"votes\":533, \"loved\":507, \"hated\":26 }, \"watched\":true, \"in_collection\":true, \"in_watchlist\":false, \"rating\":false, \"rating_advanced\":0 }, { \"season\":1, \"episode\":3, \"number\":3, \"tvdb_id\":2656081, \"title\":\"Tell It to the Frogs\", \"overview\":\"After returning to the camp with the department store survivors and an emotional reunion with his wife and son, Rick decides to go against Shane's advice and go back to Atlanta for Merle Dixon and his dropped bag of guns accompanied by Merle's younger brother, Darryl Dixon, as well as Glenn and T-Dog.\", \"first_aired\":1289797200, \"first_aired_iso\":\"2010-11-14T21:00:00-06:00\", \"first_aired_utc\":1289815200, \"url\":\"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/3\", \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-3.22.jpg\", \"images\":{ \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-3.22.jpg\" }, \"ratings\":{ \"percentage\":85, \"votes\":484, \"loved\":458, \"hated\":26 }, \"watched\":true, \"in_collection\":true, \"in_watchlist\":false, \"rating\":false, \"rating_advanced\":0 }, { \"season\":1, \"episode\":4, \"number\":4, \"tvdb_id\":2656091, \"title\":\"Vatos\", \"overview\":\"While still in search of Merle, the group tries to retrieve the bag of guns but are attacked by several living men who are also after the weapons. The group manages to grab the injured attacker; however, several of the attackers escape and take Glenn hostage. Back at camp a large group of walkers venture up the hill and take the survivors by surprise.\", \"first_aired\":1290402000, \"first_aired_iso\":\"2010-11-21T21:00:00-06:00\", \"first_aired_utc\":1290420000, \"url\":\"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/4\", \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-4.22.jpg\", \"images\":{ \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-4.22.jpg\" }, \"ratings\":{ \"percentage\":88, \"votes\":490, \"loved\":467, \"hated\":23 }, \"watched\":true, \"in_collection\":true, \"in_watchlist\":false, \"rating\":false, \"rating_advanced\":0 }, { \"season\":1, \"episode\":5, \"number\":5, \"tvdb_id\":2656101, \"title\":\"Wildfire\", \"overview\":\"Rick leads the group to the CDC after the attack on the camp. Jim must make a terrible life and death decision.\", \"first_aired\":1291006800, \"first_aired_iso\":\"2010-11-28T21:00:00-06:00\", \"first_aired_utc\":1291024800, \"url\":\"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/5\", \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-5.22.jpg\", \"images\":{ \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-5.22.jpg\" }, \"ratings\":{ \"percentage\":87, \"votes\":460, \"loved\":443, \"hated\":17 }, \"watched\":true, \"in_collection\":true, \"in_watchlist\":false, \"rating\":\"love\", \"rating_advanced\":10 }, { \"season\":1, \"episode\":6, \"number\":6, \"tvdb_id\":2656111, \"title\":\"TS-19\", \"overview\":\"Rick and the group are allowed into the CDC by a strange doctor, but all is not what it seems in their newfound haven. \", \"first_aired\":1291611600, \"first_aired_iso\":\"2010-12-05T21:00:00-06:00\", \"first_aired_utc\":1291629600, \"url\":\"http://trakt.tv/show/the-walking-dead/season/1/episode/6\", \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-6.22.jpg\", \"images\":{ \"screen\":\"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/episodes/124-1-6.22.jpg\" }, \"ratings\":{ \"percentage\":87, \"votes\":465, \"loved\":440, \"hated\":25 }, \"watched\":true, \"in_collection\":true, \"in_watchlist\":false, \"rating\":\"love\", \"rating_advanced\":10 } ]";
    ArrayList<Map> al = new Gson().fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);
    for(Map m : al){
        System.out.printf("Ep. %.0f aired on %s\n", m.get("episode"),  m.get("first_aired_iso"));
    }
}
```

This is the execution:

```
1 aired on 2010-10-31T21:00:00-05:00
2 aired on 2010-11-07T21:00:00-06:00
3 aired on 2010-11-14T21:00:00-06:00
4 aired on 2010-11-21T21:00:00-06:00
5 aired on 2010-11-28T21:00:00-06:00
6 aired on 2010-12-05T21:00:00-06:00
```

You should always let Gson do the work for you. In this case you have an list of objects (map). So tell Gson to deserialize in that way and access to the structure using generic for loop and map access.

Comment: Found this slightly more complicated than the one that worked for me.
But still, nice solution, definitely cleaner than mine. :)

Comment: Thank you for you comment, but tell me, where do you find complexity?